# Obtaining xml attributes is taking too long and also memory intensive in R

Tags: xml, r, performance, memory

I am trying to read in all the xml attributes matching certain  pattern from my xml file (shown below is a sample of my file). The actual xml file is about 400 MB in size with about 4.5 million lines of xml nodes and attributes.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<events version="1.0">
 <event time="10800.0" type="actend" person="9982471" link="21225" actType="home"  />
 <event time="10800.0" type="departure" person="9982471" link="21225" legMode="car"  />
 <event time="10800.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="9982471" vehicle="9982471"  />
 <event time="10800.0" type="actend" person="9656271" link="21066" actType="home"  />
 <event time="10800.0" type="departure" person="9656271" link="21066" legMode="car"  />
 <event time="10800.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="9656271" vehicle="9656271"  />
 <event time="99489.0" type="entered link" person="10777221" link="14182" vehicle="10777221"  />
 <event time="99498.0" type="left link" person="10777221" link="14182" vehicle="10777221"  />
 <event time="99498.0" type="entered link" person="10777221" link="14128" vehicle="10777221"  />
 <event time="99533.0" type="left link" person="10777221" link="14128" vehicle="10777221"  />
 <event time="99533.0" type="entered link" person="10777221" link="14122" vehicle="10777221"  />
 <event time="99542.0" type="left link" person="10777221" link="14122" vehicle="10777221"  />
 <event time="99542.0" type="entered link" person="10777221" link="14100" vehicle="10777221"  />
</events>
```

This is the code I am using to extract the dataframe of interest.

`library(XML)
file <- "C:/Users/S/Desktop/100.events.test.xml"
popact <- xmlParse(file)
eventsdf <- sapply(c("time","type", "person", "link", "vehicle"), function(x) xpathSApply(popact, "//event[@type='left link']|//event[@type='entered link']", xmlGetAttr, x))`

Here are the issues I am facing:

1. The code has been running for a few hours without still producing the results. Interestingly, if I remove the qualifier `"//event[@type='left link']|//event[@type='entered link']"` and use `"//event"` (i.e. reading all the attributes without specific selection), I obtain the results in about half-an-hour. How can I reduce the runtime for my code? Should I use a different approach to obtain the results I require?
2. Although the size of the file in this case is just 400 MB, the code requires about 11 GB of RAM when I run it on a cluster. Why is working with XML files and using the XML library so memory intensive? This is very important for me because I have a similar file which is of size 40 GB. A simple back of the envelope calculation shows that I might require a RAM of 1200 GB to work with this big file. Are there any techniques to manage the memory requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sapply` is only needed if there are some nodes with missing attributes.  If there are none, as in the example, we can streamline it to the following where `xpath` is your XPath expression.  Also the xpath expression here only traverses the tree of nodes once since there is only one `//` .

```
xpath2 <- "//event[@type='left link' or @type='entered link']"
t(xpathSApply(popact, xpath2, xmlAttrs))
```

Here is a timing comparison:

```
library(rbenchmark)

xpath <- "//event[@type='left link']|//event[@type='entered link']"
benchmark(orig = sapply(c("time","type", "person", "link", "vehicle"), 
                  function(x) xpathSApply(popact, xpath, xmlGetAttr, x)),
          new = t(xpathSApply(popact, xpath2, xmlAttrs)))[1:4]
```

giving:

```
  test replications elapsed relative
2  new          100    0.07    1.000
1 orig          100    0.68    9.714
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While it is helpful, it did not solve the performance issue. The code ran for  hours without producing the final result. I stopped it after 7 hours. What seems to work better is to use `xpath <- "//event"` and subsetting the data later using
`eventsdf <- subset(eventsdf, eventsdf[,'type']=="left link" | eventsdf[,'type']=="entered link")`
Can you throw any insights on why using the earlier xpath is so painfully slow?

Comment: Here is the code I used and the run time.

`library(XML)      
file <- "C:/Users/S/Desktop/100.events.test.xml"
popact <- xmlParse(file)
eventsdf <- sapply(c("time","type", "person", "link", "vehicle"), function(x) xpathSApply(popact, "//event", xmlGetAttr, x))
eventsdf <- subset(eventsdf, eventsdf[,'type']=="left link" | eventsdf[,'type']=="entered link")`

and the run time

  `user  system elapsed                                                                                                 
918.43    2.34  950.02`

Comment: Thanks Gabor. Can you please put this as a separate answer so that I can accept it? Also, some explanation on why this is fast compared to what I was using would be great.